# User specific version of extensions from Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've been developing and maintaining a Chrome extension for my company where each customer would be assigned a unique ID in the code. We've been using the ID to determine license status and login to our services (paid extension with monthly subscription fee).

So far we've hosted the extension files ourselves and had unique update URLs for each customer extension. This has been nice and simple; go to our website, click install and you're done. With the latest Chrome release, however, that installation procedure has been thwarted by Google since they now require users to install extensions by dragging and dropping the CRX files into the chrome://chrome/extensions/ tab. Unless of course your extension is available through Chrome Web Store - which leads me to the problem:

- We don't want the drag and drop CRX installation - requires Web Store.
- We don't want multiple versions of the extension (one for each customer) on the Web Store since that's a maintenance hell every time we update the extension.
- We don't want to use Web Store licensing because:

  - It requires OpenID login.
  - We sell the extension to schools with many students where the school pays the bill - not the student.
  - We don't want to lock our payment method to one browser, i.e. we want to be able to maintain licensing and payment through our or servers.
- We don't want to have users input a license key since that's too much of a risk with several thousand students having to input the key - also it requires some kind of storage (cookies/localStorage) which would eventually get cleared requiring the license key to be input again.

I'm not 100% certain that my statements are completely correct, so feel free to enlighten me if I missed something.

If they are, the question is whether or not we can somehow tailor the extension for each customer through the Web Store (using the unique ID) without needing to publish one extension per ID?

As a side question any answers that might solve the problem with another method will also be accepted.

Comment: Regarding localStorage: your app's localStorage is not going to get cleared unless your app does it (in which you'll know what's going on and can handle it appropriately), or your user does it from the JS console (in which case he'll know it broke because he was mucking around on the JS console). App localStorage will never be cleared arbitrarily by the browser -- [even when the user wipes all localStorage](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36550) (note that the linked bug is labeled "WontFix"). However, thousands of students entering a license key is a separate concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the answer below, I assume your app is a packaged app, not a hosted app.

I have a solution that's fairly similar to your current implementation, but adds one extra step for users.  For the student user, the process will work like this:

1. Download the app from the Web Store.  The app does not function yet, and launching it just displays a "Please click the activation link provided by your school/institution" message.
2. Click a link hosted on *your server* (i.e., the server where you used to host the update URL) that looks like `https://myserver.com/activateapp.php?custid=123456789`.  You host one such link for each institution you support, and it is the institution's job to provide its link to its students.  This link activates the app.

From an implementation point of view, here's how it works:

1. Host a page, `https://myserver.com/activateapp.php`, on your server.  Server-side, check that the `custid` parameter is valid.  If it is not, send a 404 error.
2. Your app has a content script that is injected into `https://myserver.com/activateapp.php` that scans the URL and picks out the customer ID. Once the app finds the ID, it stores it in localStorage. Since invalid customer IDs produce a 404 error, you know that when the content script runs, the page is not a 404 error; therefore, it is reading a valid customer ID.
3. Any time the app wants to query your services, it checks if it has a customer ID in localStorage.  If it does, it uses that ID; if it does not, it displays a message that the app has not been activated yet. Packaged apps will never have their `localStorage` erased unless your app is programmed to wipe its own storage, or the user does it from the console. Storage erasure will never "accidentally" happen. Even the strongest browser-wide data/cache purge will only clear `localStorage` from Web pages, not from apps and extensions.

For extra security -- if you don't want people randomly guessing customer IDs -- you can add an extra signature parameter, like `https://myserver.com/activateapp.php?custid=123456789&sig=2464509243`.  This extra parameter is some server-verified transformation of the customer ID (ideally a cryptographic signature or a purely random value associated with the ID in a database) that is impossible for anyone to guess.  When the request for `activateapp.php` hits the server, it checks for a valid customer ID *and* a valid corresponding signature.  Of course, this doesn't stop people who have legitimate access to a valid link from sharing the link to unauthorized people, but I expect that was a vulnerability that existed in your old system anyway.

Comment: I suggest to use [`chrome.storage.sync`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html#property-sync) over `localStorage`, because that allows users to use use the same credentials across multiple computers when using Google sync.

Comment: My boss approves of this method. Out of curiosity, what would you do to avoid sharing the extension to be as easy as giving out the activation link?

Comment: The only real security option I can think of is a institution-wide username/password that the user enters as either 1) HTTP authentication or 2) on a landing page (e.g. `enterpass.php?custid=...`) that then redirects to `activateapp.php` with the username and password passed to activation page as POST data.  Under #2, `activateapp.php` only returns a `200 OK` response if the POST data is correct, in addition to checking for a valid `custid`.

Comment: Another (not so great) option is to check the source IP of the request and verify that it is within the normal IP range of the school's computers.  This requires students to be on site (or tunneled into a computer on site) when activating the app. This works best for universities that have a designated block of IPs or that run all traffic through a proxy.

Comment: Aye, was expecting something along the lines of a login, but even then it's not safe seeing as both Javascript and localStorage can be inspected.

Comment: Well, what we're trying to do here is create a conventient replacement for entering an activation code.  If you had the student enter an activation code, there's nothing stopping them from sharing the code; instead you have them click a link (to reduce input error), so there's nothing to stop them from sharing the link. The btoom line is that an unauthorized user could still pull up a JS console and insert the customer/activation code into localStorage directly. None of this is any less safe than having an input field for the institution access code.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself ^^